# Detect WKInterfaceButton pressed continuously?

Tags: watchkit, wkinterfacebutton

WatchKit is here and comes with a very limited code for the programmers.

My question:

How can I detect if the user is pressing a WKInterfaceButton continuously?

- Selector ... forControlEvents .. are not supported.
- Touches begin ... are not supported.

Thanks for your time!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

With `WatchKit` for *watchOS 1* there is no way to detect a long press on a button. A long press is considered a `force touch`, and brings up the `force touch menu` if you have implemented one.

---

WWDC 2015 just finished, and Apple announced *watchOS 2*, which has a lot of new exciting features. Long press is not one of them (as far as I know), but `WatchKit` is now a lot less limited. Check out some of the new features here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/index.html